# IE plugin to fill form

Tags: c#, forms, internet-explorer, plugins

I have a trivial task of filling out a lot of forms on IE everyday. For different sets of data, I fill the same form atleast 30 times a day. The data I get usually from a CSV file, copy paste each data cell to appropriate text boxes in the form.
There are certain fields in the form which are constant for all data sets, which I automatically fill them using a plugin called Roboform.

What I want is a way to make an IE plugin, which can retrieve data from the CSV (or any other kind of data storage), and fill in the form.

Is there a plugin currently in the market which can do the same, or if not can someone point to a direction of how I can make one.
I'm pretty handy with Java, and basic Javascript & HTML, but willing to learn some C# if required.

PS: I can use only IE, no firefox or chrome.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you want to automatically fill a form (all its fields) from csv.

It might be an overkill for what you want but take a look at [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DistributedAutomatedBrowserTestingWithSeleniumAndBrowserStack.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.
Although I must admit - this is indeed overkill. If I'm left with nothing else, I'll have to indulge into this.